# show echo from php using ajaxForm plugin

Tags: php, jquery, forms, echo, ajaxform

I've made a registration form and used jQuery Form Plugin (ajaxForm) to save the user input to my database. I validated the input fields using javascript in my HTML file, but I checked the email and username in my Php file.

But the problem is, I don't know how to show the echo message in my html file. Like when it echoes "Username is already in use", how can i show it in my html file (as an alert)?

My code is still not complete, I have put mysql_real_escape and encrypted the password using md5. I will do it after I solve my problem. \

Here is the code in saving the form to my database.

```
<script> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        var options = {
            resetForm: true,
            }
            $('form#register').ajaxForm(options);
        }); 
</script>
```

Here is part of my php file

```
//username validation
$user_check = mysql_query("SELECT uname FROM se_reg WHERE uname='$uname'"); 
$do_user_check = mysql_num_rows($user_check); 

//email validation
$email_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM se_reg WHERE email='$email'"); 
$do_email_check = mysql_num_rows($email_check); 

//error message for username and email
if($do_user_check > 0){ 
$mess = $json_encode('Username is already in use.');
die("$mess"); 
} 

if($do_email_check > 0){ 
die("Email is already in use!"); 
}
```

database name: se
table: se_reg

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help:

```
$('#myForm1').ajaxForm({
    resetForm: true,
    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        // responseText is whatever is echoed from server <--
        // statusText is going to = success here
        // xhr is similar to jqXHR (see jquery.ajax())
        // $form is the actual form that was submitted
    }
});
```

keep in mind, all you have to do PHP side is `echo` a string

if it's going to be somthing other than a string (aka integer or boolean) be sure to wrap the value in `json_encode()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @SpYk3HH! It's now working.

I put an echo on my php file, placed the success and alerted the responseText. Thank you very much! You saved my grade :))